# Jenkins - How to make other build steps run even if previous build step fail

Tags: jenkins

I have multiple build steps in my Jenkins Free style Job.
If one of the build step fails, the the following build step doesn't get triggered.

I am Ok if the 1st build step fails as these are tests and could fail & would like to retain the $BUILD_STATUS value for reporting, but I still want the 2nd build step to run & not be skipped because build step 1 failed.

I also tried to combine both the build steps together into one but its still the same - the commands from the 2nd build step do not get executed if the commands in the 1st build step fail.
[image: error]
Thanks
Sa

Comment: If you have possibility using pipeline, it is the better option for this. Then you can get benefits of catchError mechanism of the pipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jenkins pipelines separates your pipeline into stages and steps that can be run independently.